# Trying to Get Spotify Command to work Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm having issues with my bot running spotify command. It says
`Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`

This is based on the code my friend sent me and the discord.js website.

`main.js`: built from scratch with the help of discordjs.guide. It took a while to make this work but i have suspected that something here may be a culprit too

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./handlers/config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
require('dotenv').config();

//Client Login
client.on("ready", ()=>{
    client.user.setActivity("JS: v.0.1.ch1r.canary", {type: "PLAYING"});
    console.log('Chikyoko Haruka>> System is now loaded and is ready to have fun!');
    const logch = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.chid);
    const online = {
        color: 0x0099ff,
        title: 'Beep Boop...',
        description: `Chiyoko Haruka is now active!`,
        thumbnail: {
            url: 'https://64.media.tumblr.com/02dabf2a7299753f442feee1512e326c/tumblr_o2qhk8IoJs1tydz8to1_500.gif',
        },
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
            text: config.BOT_NAME +': ' + config.BOT_VERSION ,
        },
    };
    logch.send({ embed: online });
});

//Client Start
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

//command handler
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);  
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

//Command Starter
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(config.PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        const err = {
            color: 0x0099ff,
            title: 'Beep Boop...',
            description: 'Error! Failed to execute command (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ ' + `${error}`,
            thumbnail:{
                url:'https://c.tenor.com/_3mSq0fET5oAAAAC/tenor.gif',
            },
            timestamp: new Date(),
            footer: {
                text: config.BOT_NAME +': ' + config.BOT_VERSION ,
            },
        };
        message.channel.send({ embed: err });
    }
});
```

spotify.js: based on the code my friend sent me but with added code of my self error starts at 35:39
which is  `if (status !== null && status.type === "LISTENING" && status.name === "Spotify" && status.assets !== null) {` i don't get why the bot my friend sent me works but it doesn't work on the bot im building i can't even pin point the issue so i'm very clueless at this point.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const convert = require('parse-ms');
const config = require('../handlers/config.json');


module.exports = {
    name: "spotify",
    category: "Utility",
    description: 'Gives the info of the song in which the mentioned user is litening to spotify',

   run: async (client, message, args) => {
    
        const user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;

        let status;
        if (user.presence.activities.length === 1) status = user.presence.activities[0];
        else if (user.presence.activities.length > 1) status = user.presence.activities[1];

        if (user.presence.activities.length === 0 || status.name !== "Spotify" && status.type !== "LISTENING") {
            const spotifyerr = {
                color: 0x0099ff,
                title: 'Beep Boop...',
                description: user.displayName + ' is not listening to spotify!',
                thumbnail:{
                    url:'https://c.tenor.com/_3mSq0fET5oAAAAC/tenor.gif',
                },
                timestamp: new Date(),
                footer: {
                    text: config.BOT_NAME +': ' + config.BOT_VERSION ,
                },
            };
            message.channel.send({ embed: spotifyerr });
        }

        if (status !== null && status.type === "LISTENING" && status.name === "Spotify" && status.assets !== null) {
            let image = `https://i.scdn.co/image/${status.assets.largeImage.slice(8)}`,
                url = `https:/open.spotify.com/track/${status.syncID}`,
                name = status.details,
                artist = status.state,
                album = status.assets.largeText,
                timeStart = status.timestamps.start,
                timeEnd = status.timestamps.end,
                timeConvert = convert(timeEnd - timeStart);

            let minutes = timeConvert.minutes < 10 ? `0${timeConvert.minutes}` : timeConvert.minutes;
            let seconds = timeConvert.seconds < 10 ? `0${timeConvert.seconds}` : timeConvert.seconds;
            let time = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(user.user.tag, user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setTitle("Listening to Spotify !!")
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setThumbnail(image)
                .addField("Song Name:", `\`\`\`${name}\`\`\``, true)
                .addField("Album:", `\`\`\`${album}\`\`\``, true)
                .addField("Artist:", `\`\`\`${artist}\`\`\``, true)
                .addField("Duration:", `\`\`\`${time}\`\`\``, false)
                .addField("Listening Now!", `[\`${artist} - ${name}\`](${url})`)
                .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setTimestamp()
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }


    }
}
```

As Requested here's the full on Error Log:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at run (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\commands\spotify.js:35:39)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\main.js:47:32)
    at emit (events:527:28)
    at handle (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at module.exports (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at handlePacket (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at onPacket (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at onMessage (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at onMessage (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at emit (events:527:28)
    at receiverOnMessage (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1068:20)
    at emit (events:527:28)
    at dataMessage (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:517:14)
    at getData (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:435:17)
    at startLoop (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
    at _write (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:78:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Writable.write (internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at socketOnData (c:\Users\ftaut\Desktop\Chiyoko Haruka-v0.1.ch1r.canary\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1162:35)
    at emit (events:527:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Readable.push (internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
    at callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

Error at spotify.js:35:39 is this code:

```
 if (status !== null && status.type === "LISTENING" && status.name === "Spotify" && status.assets !== null) {
```

Error at main.js:47:32 is this code:

```
client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);
```

ps: please explain to me in detail (only if you can) the issue so i can learn why that happened.

Comment: Can you share full error?

Comment: yes, i'll add the error sorry about that im fairly new to using and asking help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're checking if `status !== null`, but `status` is `undefined` and `undefined` is not the same as `null`.

Just check if `status` is truthy:

```js
if (status && status.type === "LISTENING" ...
```

Comment: thank you! i have tried your solution and it worked. but i also made a mistake on my part as i have forgot to turn on Discord Privileged gateway intents. the code now works on both my code and your solution.